# Laravel "json_extract" data is not coming

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-9

Here is the data saved in the extra_data column of a record from my FormElement model:

```
"{\"title\":\"\\u0130nput Ba\\u015fl\\u0131\\u011f\\u0131 Say\\u0131\",\"slug\":\"input_basligi_sayi\",\"type\":\"1\",\"required\":null,\"rows\":1,\"data_type\":\"number\",\"options\":null,\"length\":\"col-xl-6\"}"
```

When I try to pull with the code below, it returns null.

```
$formElements = FormElement::where(DB::raw("json_extract(extra_data, '$.type')"), 1)->get();
```

I tried this in several ways;

```
$formElements = FormElement::whereIn('id', $extraData)->whereJsonContains('extra_data', ['type' => 1])->get();
$formElements = FormElement::whereIn('id', $extraData)->whereJsonContains('extra_data->type', 1)->get();
```

How do I do this? Thanx..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in what case this issue

Add this to the model and see

```
protected $casts = [
    'extra_data' => 'json',
];
```

Comment: Yes, in my model the extra_data column is specified as an array.



    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'extra_data',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'extra_data' => 'array',
    ];